# Help with Proportion of correct responses vs age, scale vs proportion correct, and duration of time spent testing to answer (a-d)

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Hello can you help me to analyze responses to a survey and a test? I have to measure proportion of answers correct, because some individuals were given more tests than others.

I want to compare age of the individuals to their proportion correct and was thinking of doing a chi-square test for this?

Then I have a Likert scale and was trying to compare this to proportion correct. My data is not normally distributed (I think, I did a shapiro wilks test that with the scale as one variable and the proportion correct as the other variable) so I was thinking a spearmans rho?